# Match a file name that includes the path and a period within the name

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file I need to take just its name:

```
/var/www/foo/dog.tur-tles.chickens.txt
```

I want to match just the:

```
dog.tur-tles.chickens
```

I have tried this in regexer:

```
([^\/]*)$
```

This matches:

```
dog.tur-tles.chickens.txt
```

I can't figure out how to only exclude that last period.

You can assume it will always be a .txt, but I wanted to build in the ability that if a file was named `dog-turtles.txt.txt` it would see that the name is `dog-turtles.txt`.

Comment: What is the language? You do not need a regex here, I believe, unless you are using some text editor.

Comment: The language is PERL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like so: `([^\/]*)(\.).+?$`.

An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/dY0iJ5/1). Not though that this will fail for extensions such as `.tar.gz` and so on.

Comment: This is not matching `dog.tur-tles.chickens.txt` and taking out the `.txt`

Comment: What does the 2 match mean?  I'm misunderstanding this thing.  My apologies.

Comment: No particular value. You can also use `([^\/]*)\..+?$` if it makes you less confused. I usually use the brackets to try and break down the regex into digestable chunks.

Comment: I used your solution and it works very well.  I decided to just try it out.  I appreciate you continued effort to work with me on the solution.

Comment: @KirsKringle: You're welcome. That being said, please keep an eye out for possible caveats (mainly files with multiple extensions).

Answer (score 1):

Just add `.txt` to your regex and since * is greedy by default it will match everything till last .txt

```
([^\/]*)\.txt$
```

**Input:**

```
/var/www/foo/dog.tur-tles.chickens.txt.txt
/var/www/foo/dog.tur-tles.chickens.txt
```

**Output:**

```
dog.tur-tles.chickens.txt
dog.tur-tles.chickens
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tG5aW4/2)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`File::Basename.fileparse`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File%3A%3ABasename) to get the file name, then use `rindex` to get the last index of `.` and then get the required substring using `substr`:

```
use File::Basename;
$x = fileparse('/var/www/foo/dog.tur-tles.chickens.txt');
print substr($x, 0, rindex($x, '.')) . "\n";
```

Output of a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_perl_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMZTdPcUlrNWxwZk0):

```
dog.tur-tles.chickens
```

Comment: When it comes to file name parsing, regular expressions are usually not efficient *unless* there is really a very special requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = ($pathname =~ s{.*/}{}r =~ s{\.[^.]+$}{}r)
```

- substitution 1 : just remove dir
- substitution 2 : just remove extension if presente